# lavaan ERROR:some variables have no variance in group

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I get this error message when trying to compute lavaan.

My data has a similar structure to this: (this values are not real, dataset is much bigger, there's 23 items)

```
ID_1.   ID_2.   Age.    Gender. Suspect Country I1.     I2.     I3.     I4 
2   2   14  M   Si  E   5   2   5   3   
3   3   15  H   No  C   3   3   3   2   
5   5   20  H   No  C   1   1   4   1   
6   6   14  M   Si  E   2   1   3   4   
8   8   18  H   Si  E   2   1   1   5
```

Where "I" are items in a cuestionary. I am trying to test invariance in an instrument. Right now, I'm trying to group by gender.

I've checked and all the items have variance and no NAs, although there's some NAs in some of the categorical variables. In order to address this I've used:

```
INSTRUMENT[INSTRUMENT == -999] <- NA
INSTRUMENT<-na.omit(INSTRUMENT)
```

and then:

```
fit_configural<- cfa(cfaINSTRUMENT, data=INSTRUMENT, group="G")
summary(fit_configural, fit.measures = TRUE, standardized = TRUE)
```

What can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the data you show, there is no variance in age for the Gender M. Does that matter?

Comment: Forgot to specify that values in my example are not real. Just wanted to show the structure. Also I have 23 items

Comment: OK, it's worth isolating which variables are causing issues. Can you do half, to find out which half has the issue, then halve the bad half, then ......